Running ASP.NET Core 8 website from Docker Container locally works fine but not from AWS elastic beanstalk
Below is my DockerFile. I can run it from Docker Desktop and then view the website at http://localhost:8080/, but when I use the same container to start an elastic beanstalk instance, I get

502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.24.0

#See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["myproject_web.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./myproject_web.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "./myproject_web.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./myproject_web.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myproject_web.dll"]


Does the application not launch on EB, or does the application launch but is not accessible from the internet?

It launches successfully and when I go to the url is when I get the 502 error. I do see these entries in the logs: 2024/04/27 04:11:48 [error] 9130#9130: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 99.106.30.5, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.17.0.2:80/", host: "myproject.eba-myrjqagf.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com"

Is that from your on-instance logs? What is supposed to be at 99.106.30.5? Have you checked?
